# react-native-sqlite-storage simple dao

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new with JS and react native. I want to make a simple dao, which has for example method 'getAllStudents()' and returns a list of students. But when I am trying something like this, I got a promise object, and don't know how to extract a students from this.

```
    getAllStudents() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.db.transaction((tx) => {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Student', [], (tx, results) => {
                console.log("Query completed");
                var len = results.rows.length;
                let allStudents = '';
                for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    let row = results.rows.item(i);
                    console.log(`Record: ${row.name}`);
                    allStudents = allStudents + row.studentId + '. ' + row.Name + ' ' + row.surname + '\n';
                }
                resolve(allStudents);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

The function returns a promise, and you can simply do a `.then()` with it to fetch the data, something like this:

`getAllStudents()
  .then(data => {
    console.log("I got some data:",data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  })`

Alternatively, if you don't want to use promises like that, you could do an async/await call.

In the code calling your function you would do this:

`const data = await getAllStudents()`

There is a tutorial here which will help you understand async/await:
https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9

For those who have never heard of this topic before, here’s a quick intro

> Async/await is a new way to write asynchronous code. Previous options
>   for asynchronous code are callbacks and promises. Async/await is
>   actually built on top of promises. It cannot be used with plain
>   callbacks or node callbacks. Async/await is, like promises, non
>   blocking. Async/await makes asynchronous code look and behave a little
>   more like synchronous code. This is where all its power lies.

Comment: Actually I didn't mention that, but i need this query executed synchronously. I mean, when i do something like
var students = getAllStudents()
i want to have a list of students right after this invocation

Comment: Ok, but is it possible without using a "async"?
Because when I'm make a render() funcion async I got an error from react-native.
Here is my method:
https://pastebin.com/DVXfJ4CJ

Comment: Did you declare the method with the `async` keyword?